# Which verb should be used, is or was?

Tags: grammaticality

According to the sequence of tenses in the following sentence, which should be used, 'is' or 'was'?

> She got a well-paid job as she is/was proficient in both English and Chinese.

Comment: 'is' because she is still proficient in the languages unless she is now otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context.

If it is recent and the effects are still applied, I'd use *'is.'*

> She got the job as she's proficient in both English and Chinese

But, should it be a distant past, I'd use *was* (especially in storytelling).

> He got the job as a gym trainer as he *was* very strong and in shape

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems logical to apply the present tense, which can imply a continuous state of being, to her dual qualifications of speaking both English and Chinese, the correct choice in context is to use the past tense of *was*.

The usage in the balance of the sentence is determined by the opening usage of what her qualifications *were* at the time, in the past, when she received the well-paid job.